# Why do I receive a permission error in Python while trying to write to a file as admin?

Tags: python, numpy, mql4

I am trying to write to a file in a directory in Python. This file is also edited by another program (MT4). The file will write successfully when the MT4 program is not doing any actions within that directory. However, whenever the MT4 program is run, the python program throws an error.

Here is the python error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\\MQL4\\Files\\modelout.txt'
```

The python program is here:

```
from keras.models import load_model

import numpy
import os, time
import ctypes, sys

i = 0

global lastmoddate
lastmoddate = 5

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    while i > -1:
        newmoddate = os.stat("AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\MQL4\Files\indicatorout.csv")[8]
        if newmoddate != lastmoddate:
                model = load_model('tried2.h5')
                data = numpy.loadtxt("AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\MQL4\Files\indicatorout.csv", delimiter=",")
                data = numpy.array([data])
                print(data)
                outdata = model.predict(data)
                print(outdata)
                final = numpy.around(outdata, 0)
                numpy.savetxt("AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\MQL4\Files\modelout.txt", final)
                time.sleep(15)
                lastmoddate = os.stat("AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\MQL4\Files\indicatorout.csv")[8]
        else:
                time.sleep(5)
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

I used a solution to get administrator from another stack overflow post. However, I am never prompted which I imagine means python is already running as administrator.

If anyone can give any advice on how to fix this error, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Side-note: You *really* want to use raw strings with Windows file paths. You're getting lucky here (none of the components start with a character Python would interpret as an escape), but it's tempting fate. Just stick an `r` before the path strings, e.g. `data = numpy.loadtxt(r"AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\94DDB309C90B408373EFC53AC730F336\MQL4\Files\indicatorout.csv", delimiter=",")`

Comment: or use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library, and cast the Path object to a string (with `str()`) before passing it to anything in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

`Running cmd.exe as an administrator`

Since in Windows there is no `sudo` command you have to run the terminal (cmd.exe) as an administrator to achieve to the level of permissions equivalent to `sudo`.

```
Find cmd.exe in C:\Windows\system32
Right-click on it and Select Run as Administrator
It will then open the command prompt in the directory C:\Windows\system32
Go to your project directory
Execute Script
```